# ActiveSupport's class_attribute undefined

Tags: ruby

I'm comfortable using Rails but I wanted to learn more about Ruby outside of the framework and thought about writing a gem for a particular problem. I started picking apart of couple (dynamoid and mongoid) to follow their pattern. I've fallen at the first and would welcome some help.

I have a module which looks like this:

```
module MyModule
  module Document
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    include Components

    included do
      class_attribute :foo
    end
  end
end
```

This imports another module which just a convince bag for extensions

```
module MyModule
  module Components
    include Fields
  end
end
```

and finally includes another module which looks like this:

```
module MyModule
  module Fields
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      class_attribute :bar
    end
  end
end
```

This follows the pattern of the other gems.

The `class_attribute` call in `MyModule::Document` works fine, as I would expect.

My problem is that I'm getting a `` undefined method `class_attribute' for MyModule::Components:Module (NoMethodError) `` in the Fields module. Now, this seems to make sense in that `MyModule::Fields` is being included in a module, not a class, and module doesn't have a `class_attribute` method. I just can't see how these other two gems are performing this trick or if there's an idiom I'm missing?

Comment: For us we had to update one of our gems called `searchlight` to 4.x to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get your class `MyModule::Document` to be the includer of `MyModule::Fields` rather than the module `MyModule::Components`. Would this work?

```
module MyModule
  module Components
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      include Fields
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't work (for reasons I can't work out, this gives me a ```components.rb:6:in `included': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)```

Comment: Sounds like it's using the built-in `included` method rather than `ActiveSupport::Concern`. Are you sure you extended it in `Components`? I get that error if I leave that line out, but not if I leave it in.

Comment: Actually you were nearly right. I had missed the ```extend ActiveSupport::Concern``` from the MyModule::Components module. Adding this in worked. After beating my head to a bloody pulp for a good few hours this fixed it for me. Thanks for your help.